# Largest number inputted

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to get the largest input in HTML using JavaScript, but I cannot seem to get what's wrong with my code. could someone please help.

```js
var numbers = [];
var output = document.getElementById("result");

function largest() {
  var number = document.getElementById("number");
  numbers.push(number.value);
  var max = Math.max(numbers);
  alert(max);


  number.innerHTML = "";
  output.innerHTML = max;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter a number
  <input type="text" id="number" onchange="largest()"><br> Largest:
  <span id="result"></span>

</p>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Answer (score 2):

You needed a  plus (unary plus operator) and a spread `...` to handle [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) with an array

```js
var numbers = [];
var output = document.getElementById("result");

function largest() {
  var number = document.getElementById("number");
  numbers.push(+number.value);
  var max = Math.max(...numbers);
  console.log(max);


  number.innerHTML = "";
  output.innerHTML = max;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter a number
  <input type="text" id="number" onchange="largest()"><br> Largest:
  <span id="result"></span>

</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sort()` and `revers()` you can archive this too.

```js
const numbers = [];
const output = document.getElementById("result");

function largest() {
  var number = document.getElementById("number");
  numbers.push(+number.value);
  const max = numbers.sort().reverse()[0];
  number.innerHTML = "";
  output.innerHTML = max;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Enter a number
  <input type="text" id="number" onchange="largest()"><br> Largest:
  <span id="result"></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with code below

```
var max = Math.max(numbers); ===> var max = Math.max(...numbers);
```